# Type inference on `map` method of Scala collections (2.10.0-RC2)

Tags: scala, type-inference

Compiler telling me "missing parameter type" on the `p` when I do this:

```
case class MapResult(input: Any, output: Map[_ <: Any, Any]) {
  override def toString = output.map(p => input + " " + p._1 + " " + p._2 ).mkString("\n")
}
```

Then it tells me

```
identifier expected but string literal found.
[error]   override def toString = output.map(p: (Any, Any) => input + " " + p._1 + " " + p._2 ).mkString("\n")
                                                                      ^
```

for the below:

```
case class MapResult(input: Any, output: Map[_ <: Any, Any]) {
      override def toString = output.map(p: (Any, Any) => input + " " + p._1 + " " + p._2 ).mkString("\n")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you specify the type parameter types in a function literal, you need to use curly braces instead of parentheses:

```
case class MapResult(input: Any, output: Map[_ <: Any, Any]) {
  override def toString = output.map{p: (Any, Any) => input + " " + p._1 + " " + p._2 }.mkString("\n")
}
```

UPDATE: you could also wrap the parameter list in parentheses, which makes the parser happy even without curly braces:

```
case class MapResult(input: Any, output: Map[_ <: Any, Any]) {
  override def toString = output.map( (p: (Any, Any)) => input + " " + p._1 + " " + p._2 ).mkString("\n")
}
```

Here you could also use pattern matching:

```
case class MapResult(input: Any, output: Map[_ <: Any, Any]) {
  override def toString = output.map{ case (k: Any, v: Any) => input + " " + k + " " + v }.mkString("\n")
}
```

As for the reason why the compiler forces you to specify the parameter type here, I honestly have no idea. I could not reproduce it in scala 2.10-RC1.

Comment: Not true: `List(1,2,3).map( (i: Int) => i + 1)` works perfectly. Or was this changed in 2.10?

Comment: You're right thanks, I updated the post to mention that it also works if you wrap the parameter list in parentheses. For what it's worth, I personnaly never use this notation as it is needlessly verbose, and curly braces are more natural anyway.